# $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{((y+y_0)^2+x_0^2)^r} dy$

Tags: integration

I have to estimate the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{((y+y_0)^2+x_0^2)^r} dy,$$ for $r\in \mathbb{R}^+$. I am a little amazed that Sage and Wolfram Alpha have nothing to say about it, and that Gradshteyn-Ryzhik doesn't seem to have anything on it either; it feels like a rather natural integral, the denominator being a distance function.

Of course I realize that, if I just expand $1/((y+y_0)^2+x_0^2)^r$ into a Taylor series around $y=-y_0$ and integrate term-by-term, I am not going to get something convergent; what I get is an asymptotic formula. But what is the right order of magnitude of the error term when the formula gets cut off at the $k$th term?

For instance: let $f(y)=1/((y+y_0)^2+(x_0^2))^r$ and write $$f(y) = f(y_0) + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{2} O^*(\max_t f''(t)).$$ Then we get an error term of size $O(1/x_0^{2 r + 3})$. If we go up to a higher-order approximation, we obtain an error term of the form $O(1/x_0^{2(r+k)+1})$ for higher $k$. But can one also give an error term that depends on $y_0$ and not just on $x_0$, and thus is better when $x_0$ is large and $y_0$ is much larger still?

Note: also asked on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3218848).

Note 2: just to be clear - the easy estimate (obtained by a cheap version of Laplace) is 
$$\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{(x_0^2+y_0^2)^r} + O^*\left(\frac{2 r \cdot \sqrt{2 \pi}}{e^{3/2} x_0^{2 r + 2}}\right).$$ That is fine if $x_0 \asymp y_0$, but we would like to do better than that in general, particularly in the tricky case $y_0\ggg x_0\ggg 1$. Here $O^*(\text{X})$ means "something of absolute value at most $X$".

Comment: One can indeed if one considers the integral from $-y_0/2$ to $y_0/2$ separately from the rest of the integral, but there has to be a more elegant way.

Comment: The question is unclearly formulated. Should  such an estimate depend on $x_0,y_0,r$?

Comment: The minimum value of the denominator equals $(x_0^2)^r$. This implies the integral is less than $\sqrt{2\pi} (x_0^{-2})^r$.

Comment: Take $r$ fixed and assume $0<x_0\leq y_0$. Yes, the estimate ought to depend on $x_0$, $y_0$ and $r$ (though, as I said, one can give a bound that depends only on $x_0$ and $r$).

Comment: Change $y+y_0=z$ to this end.

Comment: Sure, either way. As I said, one can get a bound of size $(1+o(1)) \sqrt{2\pi}/y_0^{2 r} + O(\exp(-y_0^2/8)/y_0 x_0^{2 r})$ by splitting the integral, but there has to be a more elegant way.

Comment: Ask it at MSE which is a right forum for such type questions.

Comment: Just did. We shall see.

Comment: You might want to try Mathematica’s AsymptoticIntegrate

Comment: @EGME: I did that.  Does not work.

Comment: @user64494 I presume you used version 12, the function has been updated ...

Comment: Does it give something better than what you get if you split the integral at a certain value of $|y|$?

Comment: For expansions for $r\gg 0$, I'd have looked in texts about the Laplace method for asymptotic expansions, e.g. https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~mevans/amm/lecture04.pdf

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do a cheap variant.

Comment: perhaps going to complex domain, writing $(y+y_0)^2+x_0^2=(y+y_0+ix_0)(y+y_0-ix_0)$, would allow for some simplifying contour integration/residue computation...

Comment: Hm - I'm a bit skeptical. I'm getting this integral after applying the saddle-point method to something else to begin with. And yes, cutting off the integral into two chunks is basically a cheap variant of the Laplace method ("cheap" in that the exponent is already quadratic, and thus many complications do not appear).

Comment: To be more precise: for $y_0\geq x_0$, splitting the integral gives a bound $(1 + O_{r,\rho}(1/y_0^2)) \sqrt{2\pi}/(x_0^2+y_0^2)^r +O(\exp(-\rho y_0^2/2)/y_0 x_0^{2 r})$, for any value of $\rho \in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

I would have liked to say this in comments, but the tex integrals make it impractical. This is not an answer but a reformulation. We can change the integrand slightly:

$$I(r)=I(r,x_0,y_0)= \int _{-\infty} ^{+\infty} e^{-y^2} \frac{dy}{((y+y_0)^2+x_0^2)^r}.$$ Multiplying by $\Gamma (r)$ we see that this becomes (after a change of variables)

$$ \Gamma (r)I(r)= \sqrt{2\pi}\int _0^{\infty} \frac{du}{u} u^r \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+u)}} e^{-(ux_0^2+y_0^2\frac{u}{1+u})}.$$ Hopefully, the latter integral can be estimated more easily.

Comment: It doesn't look so simple. Does it give a better estimate?

Comment: very helpful indeed; note that there is a factor $\sqrt{2\pi}$ missing.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: Thank you. I have added the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ factor

Answer (score 3):

<sub>For $r$ an integer $\geq 2$ you could start from the closed form expression for $r=2$ and then obtain larger integer values of $r$ by differentiation with respect to $x_0$. The result for $r=2$ is</sub>

<sub>$$
I_2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{((y+y_0)^2+x_0^2)^2} dy=\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi }}{2x_0^2}+\frac{\pi e^{x_0^2/2}}{4x_0^3 e^{y_0^2/2}}(w+\bar{w}),
$$</sub>

<sub>with $z=x_0+iy_0$, $w=(1-x_0z)\text{erfc}(z/\sqrt{2})\exp(i x_0 y_0)$.</sub>

---

For the large-$x_0$ asymptotics I follow the suggestion of Venkataramana:

$$I_r=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{((y+y_0)^2+x_0^2)^r} dy=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Gamma(r)}\int_0^\infty\frac{u^{r-1}  }{\sqrt{2 u+1} }e^{-u \left(\frac{y_0^2}{2 u+1}+x_0^2\right)}\,du$$
Now for $x_0\rightarrow\infty$ the integrand contributes mainly near $u=0$, so I may replace $2u+1\mapsto 1$, and then find 
$$I_r\rightarrow\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(x_0^2+y_0^2\right)^{-r}.$$
Here are some numerical checks, blue is the exact integral, gold the large-$x_0$ form, all plotted as a function of $x_0$ for different values of $y_0$ and $r$.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

<sub>top row from left to right: $y_0=1,r=2$; $y_0=1,r=4$

bottom row from left to right: $y_0=10,r=2$; $y_0=10,r=4$.</sub>

Comment: MMA finds the integral under consideration even for $r=4$ (I think for bigger integer values of $r$ too.) . The result uses compexes, the one is huge and unclear.

Comment: The asymptotics are certainly right (they match what I said below). Still, the point is that we want an error term that goes to $0$ as rapidly as possible in the case when $x_0\to \infty$ slowly and $y_0\to \infty$ more rapidly. I'll make this clearer in the text of the question.

Comment: Deleted former comments with typos. Here is the correct one: The exponent in the second integral (over $u$) has saddle points at $u=-\frac{1}{2}(-1\pm i\ \frac{y_{0}}{x_{0}})$ which contribute to the asymptotics as well. Presumably with a suppressing (for $y_{0}>x_{0}$) prefactor $\propto exp(x^2_{0}/2−y^2_{0}/2)$, though

Answer (score 2):

Mainly for purposes of comparison, 
let me flesh out what I called "a cheap version of Laplace". Write $\sigma = 2 r$.

Choose $\rho\in (0,1)$. Let $g(y) = 1/(x_0^2+y^2)^{\sigma/2}$.
  Then $$g''(y) = \frac{-\sigma}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{\sigma}{2} + 1}} +
  \frac{\sigma \left(\frac{\sigma}{2}+1\right) \cdot 2 y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{\sigma}{2} + 2}}$$
  and so $|g''(y)|\leq \sigma (\sigma+1)/(x^2+y^2)^{\sigma/2+1}$. 
Let $I$ be the interval
 $\lbrack (1-\rho) y_0,
  (1+\rho) y_0\rbrack$. Then, for $y\in I$,
  $|g''(y)|\leq \sigma (\sigma+1)/((1-\rho) l_0)^{\sigma+2}$,
where $l_0 = \sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}$,
  and so
  $$g(y) = g(y_0) + g'(y_0) (y- y_0) + O^*\left(c_0 (y-y_0)^2\right),$$
  where $c_0 = \sigma (\sigma+1)/2 ((1-\rho) l_0)^{\sigma+2}$.
  Thus, by cancellation,
  $$\int_I g(y) e^{-(y-y_0)^2/2} dy = 
  \int_I g(y_0) e^{-(y-y_0)^2/2} dy +
  O^*\left(\int_I c_0 (y-y_0)^2 e^{-(y-y_0)^2/2} dy\right).$$
Since $g'(y)<0$ for $y\geq 0$,
we also know that $g(y)<g(y_0) + c_0 (y-y_0)^2$ 
for $y>(1+\rho) y_0$. We conclude that
  $$\begin{aligned}\int_{(1-\rho) y_0}^{\infty} g(y) e^{-(y-y_0)^2/2} dy 
  &\leq g(y_0) \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2/2} dy +
  c_0 \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 e^{-y^2/2} dy\\
  &= g(y_0) \sqrt{2\pi} + c_0 \sqrt{2\pi} 
  =  \left(1 + \frac{\sigma (\sigma+1)}{2 (1-\rho)^{\sigma+2} l_0^2}\right)
  \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{l_0^\sigma} .\end{aligned}$$

It remains to consider $y\leq (1-\rho) y_0$. Since $g(y)\leq g(0) = 1/x_0^\sigma$,
  $$\begin{aligned}\int_{-\infty}^{(1-\rho) y_0} g(y) e^{-(y-y_0)^2/2} dy &=
  \frac{1}{x_0^\sigma} \int_{-\infty}^{-\rho y_0} e^{-y^2/2} dy \\ &\leq
  \frac{1}{x_0^\sigma (\rho y_0)} \int_{-\infty}^{-\rho y_0} y e^{-y^2/2} dy =
  \frac{e^{-\rho^2 y_0^2/2}}{\rho x_0^\sigma y_0}.
  \end{aligned}$$

Thus we obtain
  $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-(y-y_0)^2/2}}{(x_0^2+y^2)^{\sigma/2}} dy
  \leq \left(1 + \frac{\sigma (\sigma+1)}{2 (1-\rho)^{\sigma+2} l_0^2}\right)
  \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{l_0^\sigma} +
  \frac{e^{-\rho^2 y_0^2/2}}{\rho x_0^\sigma y_0}$$
for any $0<\rho<1$.

Hardly very powerful or elegant, but I wonder: (a) is the above qualitatively optimal? That is, are the lesser-order terms of the right order? (b) can one give an even quicker proof of the same or a stronger bound?

Comment: In particular, I'd like to see that pesky $\rho$ disappear.